# getattr is returning character '>' instead of mehtod

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr

I have a class defined in feat.py

```
class feat:
  def __init__(self):
    print 'feat init '
    pass


  def do_something(self):
    return true
```

Now I am calling the following:

```
from feat import *
f=feat()
for i in dir(f): #feature_functions:
        i_str = str(i)
        print 'f has this attribute',  hasattr(f,i)
        print 'f has  attribute value',  getattr(f,i)
```

I am getting output:

```
feat init 
f has this attribute True 
f has attribute value >
```

I tried using i_str like the following

```
print 'f has this attribute',  hasattr(f,i_str)
print 'f has  attribute value',  getattr(f,i_str)
```

I am getting the same output.

Shouldn't the output look like the following?

```
f has this attribute True 
f has attribute value <function do_something at 0x10b81db18>
```

Would appreciate any suggestion. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I made minor changes to your code to show more clearly what is going on:

```
from feat import *
f=feat()
for i in dir(f): #feature_functions:
        print i, 'f has this attribute',  hasattr(f,i)
        print i, 'f has  attribute value',  getattr(f,i)
```

And this is the output I get:

```
feat init 
__doc__ f has this attribute True
__doc__ f has  attribute value None
__init__ f has this attribute True
__init__ f has  attribute value <bound method feat.__init__ of <feat.feat instance at 0x0000000004140FC8>>
__module__ f has this attribute True
__module__ f has  attribute value feat
do_something f has this attribute True
do_something f has  attribute value <bound method feat.do_something of <feat.feat instance at 0x0000000004140FC8>>
```

Which is what we both expect. The chief difference is that the changed code isn't calling `str()`. I suspect you may have redefined `str()`, possibly in some earlier iteration of the code, and the redefinition is still lying around in your shell session's namespace. If so, starting a fresh interpreter session with only the code you present should solve the problem.